# Rectangle and Screen Collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently learning collisions of rectangles and I am following a video trying to make a rectangle bounce off the edges of the screen. But for some reason, the rectangle is just blinking on the side of the screen. Please let me know where I made I mistake. Thanks!!!

```
import pygame, sys

def bounce():
    global x_velocity, y_velocity
    ball.x += x_velocity
    ball.y += y_velocity
    if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= screen_height: 
        ball.y = -ball.y
    if ball.right >= screen_width or ball.left <= 0:
        ball.y *= -ball.y
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), ball)

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Ball
x_velocity = 2
y_velocity = 4
ball = pygame.Rect(475, 275, 25, 25)

while True:
    # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    bounce()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you detect the rect has collided with a screen edge in the bounce function, you just need to reverse the x_velocity or y_velocity.

```
def bounce():
    global x_velocity, y_velocity
    ball.x += x_velocity
    ball.y += y_velocity
    if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= screen_height: 
        #ball.y = -ball.y
        y_velocity = -y_velocity
    if ball.right >= screen_width or ball.left <= 0:
        #ball.y *= -ball.y
        x_velocity = -x_velocity
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), ball)
```

Comment: Ahhh I see now, instead of using the y-coordinate of the ball, I have to use the velocity, sorry for being dumb. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Since this works, could you mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Oh yeah no problem!